# Code execution takes a long time in random places on rails, mysql, debian stack

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, debian, sidekiq

I have started to see that sometimes some process takes a really long time to run. In logs, it looks like:

```
I, [2023-04-27T20:46:35.949229 #47058772807600 ]   Response body   *****
I, [2023-04-27T21:20:57.068795 #47058772807600 ]   Maker   Company: 94
```

Usually these lines are following each other immediately, "Response body" line is the end of a loop, and "Maker" is printed in the beginning of a loop. So, it took 34 minutes to start a new loop iteration. The loop is processing expense entries. I have a slow query logging enabled on MySQL, but nothing has got logged. syslog is also not showing anything. I'm puzzled how to find out what has taken so long.

edit: My slow query logging had got stopped a while ago. Probably during a database update. But I have it now enabled for the next time I see an event like this.

Comment: operating system sometimes bock the internal scheduler, so that other processes can not do their job, but you should have to many of them, usually with an update can be this resolved, why the kernel needs that time, can be maybe determined at specialized forums

Comment: @nbk Would that affect all threads in my app? Because, when this one thread was seemingly idle, other similar threads were able to work normally. These threads are Sidekiq workers.

Comment: sometimes the complete system freezes, a closer look shows that the scheduler doesn't work all processes any more, system calls have a higher priority of course, but some things take even so so much time that it is noticeable. it is actually quite fascinating, search for the cuprit